# Position of Keyboard Android at SoftInputMethod=AdjustPan

Tags: android, keyboard, resize, focus, textview

I'm having some big troubles with the position of the keyboard on one of my applications : i need to set my keyboard to stay under a specific TextView and not the focused one.

Here in the image an example of what i want to achieve.

[image]

I'm using WindowSoftInputMethod=AdjustPan.
Is there any way to set the position(or the target) for the keyboard? thanks in advance

Comment: Is there anybody who knows the answer?
I'm still searching with no results..